# In Scala, why does getInstance fail to work with GregorianCalendar?

Tags: scala

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
```

Works in Java

```
java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
```

Works in Scala

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
```

Fails in Scala. getInstance is not a member of object java.util.GregorianCalendar

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are no static in scala, rather there are in singleton objects and methods in them, and so they are not considered inherited, even when defined in java. `getInstance` is defined on `Calendar`. In java, calling it on `GregorianCalendar` does call the exact same method as calling it on `Calendar`. In scala, you have to call it on `Calendar`. (BTW, calling it on GregorianCalendar in java is rather misleading)

Comment: +1 Totally agree about the misleading usage in java, this thing always bothered me.

Comment: But if you call it on GregorianCalendar the return type is different right? It's Calendar instead of GregorianCalendar